# Filter categories used with Custom Structure Permalink

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, filters

I'm using a "Custom Structure" permalink setting:

```
http://mysite.com/%category%/%postname%/
```

However, when the post belongs to uncategorized, or to more than one category, this produces unwanted URL structures.

Basically, I want to find out if I can run a filter on this so that "Uncategorized" and any child categories of Uncategorized are removed from this URL pattern.

Appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: There are various category/custom permalink questions here already, did you have a good search on this site for solutions prior to posting your question, if so, please add some references to what you've read and tried so far. If not, please check some of the existing questions.